# Mule messages currently in the VM Queue

Tags: queue, mule, esb

How can I get copy of all messages (or references of all messages) that are on a VMQueue?

I want to loop through the list of messages that are currently on VMQueue, check the payload of every message, and based on that make decision about next step in the flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consume them with a `vm:inbound-endpoint`, you can't peek or browse them without actually taking them out of the queue.